# Is there a direct way to get user profile picture on facebook?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook API - How do I get a facebook user's profile image through the FB api (without requiring the user to Allow app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821061/facebook-api-how-do-i-get-a-facebook-users-profile-image-through-the-fb-api)

I can do a get at http://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID/picture

but i would like to find a way to open image direct without do a get on this url.

is there a way to do it?

Comment: What is more direct than the url? Whats your usecase?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821061/facebook-api-how-do-i-get-a-facebook-users-profile-image-through-the-fb-api