# How do I get picture's profile using the api php facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, api, image

Hear is my code. I would like to get picture with api php facebook.
The variable $photo returns NULL value.

```
<?php
    $profile = $facebook->api('/<idfacebook>');
    $photo = $facebook->api('/'.$profile['username'].'/picture');
?>
```

Comment: This might help you...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821061/facebook-api-how-do-i-get-a-facebook-users-profile-image-through-the-fb-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From stackoverflow.com/questions/2821061

"Simply fetch the data through this url:
    http://graph.facebook.com/sarfraz.anees/picture

Replace sarfraz.anees (my name) with name of the user you want to get the photo of.
You can use the PHP's `file_get_contents` function to read that url and process the retrieved data.

Resource:`http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api`

Note: In php.ini, you need to make sure that openssl extension is enabled to use the `file_get_contents` function of PHP to read that url.  "