# How can i get image from facebook

Tags: c#, facebook

I want to display images upload by Facebook user to my asp.net(c#) website. i have access token of Facebook user

Answer (score 0):

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{userName}/picture
```

Resource:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

edit:
there is another post here with the same question:

[Facebook API - How do I get a Facebook user's profile image through the Facebook API (without requiring the user to "Allow" the application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821061/facebook-api-how-do-i-get-a-facebook-users-profile-image-through-the-fb-api)