# Display facebook user images in PhoneGap (Android)

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova

I have a very simple use case. I have an xhr object  of ids of facebook users. 
Now I just want to display the images of the users in the following way.

```
    xhr.objects.forEach(function (user) {
 $('#userimage').append( '< img src="https://graph.facebook.com/"+user.user_id+"/picture/?type=small"/>');
                                                    });
```

For some reason this is not working. The images are not being displayed. I have added "https://graph.facebook.com" to allow access. Also images from the local web server are being displayed properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your string should read

```
picture?type=small
```

not

```
picture/?type=small
```

So the correct URL is:

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/"+user.user_id+"/picture?type=small"
```

See [how do I get a facebook users profile image through the fb api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821061/facebook-api-how-do-i-get-a-facebook-users-profile-image-through-the-fb-api) for details.