# access facebook photo for matrimonial site

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my matrimonial site, i want to add the three functionality, Upload photo from local disk, upload photo and modify photo into pencil sketch, Get photo from facebook account.

i have analyzed and posted created some threads for access FB Photos. but now That suggested code are require the APPId, Security Key.  but dont see any where user FB username and password.

Can you please show the right direction for this request. how to access FB photos from my site. From user end we can request only FB username and password.

Right now analyzing towards of this below snippet. even this snippet return 0 values. 
now my doubt is, how my APPID will use for accessing others photo album in FB.

```
require '../src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
 $config = array();
  $config['appId'] = '109181812948600';
  $config['secret'] = 'edflmlkmlkmlkmlkmlk7079e9d5884';
  $config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $uid = $facebook->getUser();
  echo $uid;
```

Comment: need to see your code first

Comment: You need to read about [Facebook's Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) and [OAuth](http://oauth.net/documentation/getting-started/). You'll get your exact answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821061/facebook-api-how-do-i-get-a-facebook-users-profile-image-through-the-fb-api

Comment: This question is very broad. Move step by step and read more about the (1) Facebook Authentication using PHP/Javascript SDK (2) add permissions (3) uploading photos (4) get photos etc.. there are many discussions on these individual topics, and good documentation at the developers site: http://developers.facebook.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access profile pictures you need authentication. You can use [OAuth.io](http://oauth.io) for easy implementation of OAuth. For more details you can visit their website : https://oauth.io/#/docs