# Getting facebook profile while signup with facebook in liferay

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, liferay, liferay-6

I am trying to use the liferay inbuild facebook signin feature. By default facebook connect only stores first name,lastname,email and gender.
I want to get the profile picture of user from facebook and store in the database as userpotrait of a user when he sign up with facebook. How can do it in liferay?

Answer (score 0):

You make the url for the profile picture of the user as -

> `http://graph.facebook.com/<USERID>/picture?type=normal`

Answer (score 0):

Try below **URL** to get facebook profile image.

**http://graph.facebook.com/{your user name}/picture**

You can easily get api for get this profile image for facebook also below link might help you.

[Facebook API - How do I get a Facebook user's profile image through the Facebook API (without requiring the user to "Allow" the application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821061/facebook-api-how-do-i-get-a-facebook-users-profile-image-through-the-fb-api)

For Store the image you will need to convert as a byte steam and store it using below Util class

```
UserServiceUtil.updatePortrait(long userId, byte[] bytes)
```

Hope this helps !