# Android Social media Login integration : Profile data to android local storage

Tags: android, facebook, android-googleapiclient

I am implementing google/facebook login for an android application. 
Now, this is pretty straight forward to fetch information like user email and name, birthday etc. 
Although, I am curious about what is the best way to handle the profile image photo.

There has been a very good tutorial on how to get this data in a async task -
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1

But, precisely, I need to know if we access the google photo URL( OR facebook URL) everytime to show it on the app? Or should we cache it by storing a local copy on the device and accessing it afterwards from there?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

To get the user's profile pic, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821061/facebook-api-how-do-i-get-a-facebook-users-profile-image-through-the-facebook).

As far as the storing image part is concerned, for quick access, store it on the device for instances when the internet connectivity is poor or non-existent.